# Mail Attachments with byte array

Tags: java, arrays, email, byte

I got a javax.mail.Session named lSession, and a MimeMessage lMessage :

```
Session lSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
MimeMessage lMessage = new MimeMessage(lSession);
```

I got a List of Byte Array who contains file's representations :

```
List <byte[]> pPiecesJointes
```

I try to attach these file to the message, but I can't fix it....

```
if(!pPiecesJointes.isEmpty()){
    lMultipart = new MimeMultipart();
    lMessageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    // text message
    lMessageBodyPart.setText(pMessage);
    lMultipart.addBodyPart(lMessageBodyPart);
    for(int i = 0; i < pPiecesJointes.size(); i++){
        lMessageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        /* ?????? How add attachment in lMessageBodyPart with a Byte Array ?
        */ 
        lMultipart.addBodyPart(lMessageBodyPart);
    }
    lMessage.setContent(lMultipart);
}

Transport.send(lMessage);
```

Please, if somebody knows who attach the file with a byte array ?

Comment: Look into `MimeBodyPart#setDataHandler(...)`. DataHandler has API's for handling DataSource which can internally handle byte arrays.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 MimeBodyPart att = new MimeBodyPart(); 
ByteArrayDataSource bds = new ByteArrayDataSource(bytearray, "AttName"); 
att.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(bds)); 
att.setFileName(bds.getName());
```

Comment: This is working : DataHandler lDataHandler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(fichierByteVO.getFile(), fichierByteVO.getMIMEType()));
     lMessageBodyPart.setDataHandler(lDataHandler);

Answer (score 2):

Try this code,

```
DataHandler lDataHandler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(fichierByteVO.getFile(), fichierByteVO.getMIMEType())); 
lMessageBodyPart.setDataHandler(lDataHandler);
```

Comment: What is `fichierByteVO`?