# Spring email add attachment from url

Tags: java

```
@Async
public void sendWithAttachment(String to, String subject, String text, String attachmentUrl) {
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
    try {

        mimeMessagePreparator.prepare(mimeMessage);
        mimeMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
        mimeMessage.setText(text);

        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

        URL url = new URL(attachmentUrl);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        InputStreamSource inputStreamSource = () -> inputStream;

        helper.addAttachment("GuideVerify.png", inputStreamSource);

        javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Not sended", e);
    }
    log.info("Sended");
}
```

> java.io.IOException: Exception writing Multipart

How can I send an attachment by extracting it from the URL?

Comment: This answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/45285386/4693532 should help you.

Comment: Yes! This really helped me, thank you.