# java How to combine itextpdf and java mail?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, itext, jakarta-mail

hey i'm working on a web application and i have problems to combine 2 features (build a pdf and send it as attachment with a email). Both parts are working separately, but i don't know how to get the file path of the creaded PDF to add it to the mail attachment.

The following are the importent codesnippets:

1. I create a new PDF file (with itext 5) with the java servlet CreatePDF and show it in a new tab:

CreatePDF Servlet:

```
    //initial new ByteArrayOutputStream
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    //get absolute path of the logo
    String relativeLogoWebPath = "/logo.jpg";
    String absoluteLogoDiskPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(relativeLogoWebPath);

    //build PDF with itextpdf
    new BuildPDF(baos, acc, absoluteLogoDiskPath, header, body, footer, vat);

    // setting the content type
    response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate, post-check=0,precheck=0");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setContentLength(baos.size());

    // write ByteArrayOutputStream to the ServletOutputStream
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    baos.writeTo(os);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
```

BuildPDF Class:

```
public BuildPDF(ByteArrayOutputStream baos, Accounting acc, String absolutLogoPath, 
  Collection<String> header, Collection<String> body, Collection<String> footer, Double vat){
    //init document
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 60, 30, 140, 90);
    document.setMarginMirroring(false);

    //init pdf writer
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
    writer.setBoxSize("art", new com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle(36, 54, 559, 788));

    //add header and footer
    HeaderFooter event = new HeaderFooter(header, footer, absolutLogoPath);
    writer.setPageEvent(event);

    //open the document
    document.open();

    //add title and body
    addTitle(document, acc)
    addBody(document, acc, body, vat, writer);

    //close document and pdf writer
    document.close();
    writer.close();
}
```

2. In the other tab I go to the next jsp page and after a button click (to open the servlet SendAccouningPage) it should be possible to send this creaded pdf with a email (with java mail):

SendAccountingPage Servlet:

```
//TODO: get path of created PDF
String[] attachFiles = new String[1]; 
//attachFiles[0] = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("pdfPath");
//request.getSession().removeAttribute("pdfPath");

EmailUtility.sendEmailWithAttachments(host, port, fromMail, passwort,
     mail, subject, message, attachFiles);
```

EmailUtility Class:

```
 public static void sendEmailWithAttachments(String host, String port,
        final String userName, final String password, String toAddress,
        String subject, String message, String[] attachFiles)
        throws AddressException, MessagingException {

    // sets SMTP server properties
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.user", userName);
    properties.put("mail.password", password);

    // creates a new session with an authenticator
    Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
        }
    };
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

    // creates a new e-mail message
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
    InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());

    // creates message part
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/html");

    // creates multi-part
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // adds attachments
    if (attachFiles != null && attachFiles.length > 0) {
        for (String filePath : attachFiles) {
            MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            try {
                attachPart.attachFile(filePath);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
        }
    }

    // sets the multi-part as e-mail's content
    msg.setContent(multipart);

    // sends the e-mail
    Transport.send(msg);

}
```

So is there a way to get the file path of the creaded pdf and store it  e.g. into the session? (and if yes: How resistant is this path? Is it lost if I close the tab with the created pdf?)

If not:

How can I combine it otherwise?

Do i have to save the pdf (if yes: Which chances do I have to do and is it possible to save it only temporary?)

Comment: I've answered your question, but I'd like to know why you chose to use iText 5 instead of iText 7. There could be more than one reason. For instance: it's a legacy project, and iText 5 is already in the codebase. However, the answer I'm really looking for is: how can we promote iText 7? How can we increase the adoption of iText 7? I have the impression that developers aren't aware that they can make money by developing add-ons on top of the [iText 7 platform](https://itextpdf.com/itext-developer-platform).

Comment: Hey the reason is simple: This is my first web projekt, so I had to learn a lot of new stuff until development. I worked earlier with iText 5, so I knew this would work like i want to. So i saved a bit Time to use the older known version =) But i like iText and I'm sure I will work into iText 7 when I finished this projekt. (Maybe I will change the version in this project too if I have time left after finalize this project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the PDF in memory using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` (named `baos`), and then you write this file to the output stream of the servlet:

```
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(os);
```

That is good practice, but there's also an alternative way.
The `ByteArrayOutputStream` has a method called [`toByteArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray()), so you could also do it like this:

```
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
os.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Now you have the complete file in the `byte[]` named `bytes`, you need to adapt your `EmailUtility` class so that it accepts a byte array instead of the path to a file. That's explained in the answer to the following question: [Mail Attachments with byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083574/mail-attachments-with-byte-array):

```
MimeBodyPart att = new MimeBodyPart(); 
ByteArrayDataSource bds = new ByteArrayDataSource(byte, "application/pdf"); 
att.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(bds));
att.setFileName(bds.getName());
```

And that's how you send a mail with an attachment of a file that is created in memory and never stored as a file on disk on the server.

Comment: Hey thx for the answer. I change it that way but now i get a javax.mail ParseException: In Conten-Type string <result.pdf> expected '/', got null

Comment: (The changes more spezific:) I save the byte[] file in the session and get it in SendAccountingPage. I also change the parameter from the EmailUtility from String[] attachFile to byte[] and call it at 1. parameter in new ByteArrayDataSource(attachFile, "result.pdf");

Comment: Your comments look like English, but it's an English I don't understand.

Comment: Haha ok I'm sorry. I'm not a great spoke talent and not in practice. I try it again:

Comment: I change my code as described above, but now i get every time this Exeption: "javax.mail.internet.ParseExeption: In Content-Type string <result.pdf>, expected '/', got null".

Comment: (additional changes:) 1. I save the byte[] bytes (in the servlet CreatePDF) into the session of the projekt (response.getSession().setAttribute("pdf", bytes)) and call it in the other servlet (SendAccountingPage: byte[] atteachFile = (byte[]) response.getSession().getAttribute("pdf")).  2. After that I call the method EmailUtility.sendEmailWithAttachments(host, port, fromMail, passwort,
     mail, subject, message, attachFiles); I change the last parameter type from String[] attachFiles to byte[] attachFiles and use this parameter as 1. parameter of the construktor for the ByteArrayDataSource

Comment: That's a JavaMail question, not an iText question. I can only help you with JavaMail questions. Also: you shouldn't use comments to add code, make a list,... As you can see yourself, it's very hard to read. Either update your existing question, or post a new question (because this sounds like a new question to me).

Comment: ps: Solution of the 2. Problem:  ByteArrayDataSource bds = new ByteArrayDataSource(attachFile, "application/pdf"); 
        att.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(bds));
        att.setFileName(title);

Comment: OK, thank you for letting me know. I updated my answer for further reference. Also a big thanks for accepting my answer.